# I'm looking to make a volumetric material only show up when Light hits it

Tags: modeling, eevee-render-engine, shader-nodes, volumetrics

I've done this with a Principled BSDF to make a light cycle on my earth scene, and I want to do the same with the volumetric atmosphere, but it doesn't seem to work with volume the same way a material does. Ideas?

Comment: Can you illustrate the effect you want to achieve? (Volume scatter will only scatter where there is light, anyway, for example, ... you want some extra special effect?)

Comment: @RobinBetts 
[link](https://imgur.com/opggiwF)
This is somewhat the affect I'm trying to get. I want to capture that halo around my earth, like fresnal.
When I use a volumetric in a sphere then it's visible even if the sun lamp isn't looking at it

Comment: I think you may have more luck, here, stating the base problem, maybe illustrated with your picture,  than trying to fix your proposed solution. Your choice, of course. You say: 'like Fresnel'. Maybe explain why Fresnel, itself, is not doing it for you.

Comment: @RobinBetts I'm not sure why fresnel doesn't work or I may not be using it correctly, but the thing is, the method I'm using works, just not when I use a Principled volume in the volume outport, I can swap the volume for a BSDF and throw it into the Surface of the material output and it works, But I'm trying to do a volumetric atmosphere. Maybe it's not something I can do I don't know.